# Cannot print values returned from CUDA kernel

Tags: arrays, cuda

I am working on swapping the variable of V1 and V3 at the same node. However, I cannot initialise the values 16 and 31 to the arrays. It might be a silly mistake that I made but I've spend an hour debugging my codes. It only kept printing '0' of every array at the `printf` output.

Can anyone spot the mistake in my codes? Here is my code:

```
 #include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>


#define threads 1024  //define the number of thread to use
#define blocks 4 //define the number of blocks to use


//Kernal Function
__global__ void Initial(double* V1, double* V3, int NX, int NY)
{
    unsigned int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (idx <= NX * NY)
    {
        V1[idx] = 16;
        V3[idx] = 31;
    }

}


__global__ void Add2D(double* V1 , double* V3, int NX, int NY)
{
    unsigned int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    

    if (idx <= NX * NY)
    {
        double tmp = V1[idx] ;
        V1[idx] = V3[idx + NX];
        V3[idx + NX] = tmp;

    }
}


int main(void) {

    //number of nodes 
    int NX = 5;
    int NY = 5;
    int N = NY * NX;

    size_t bytes =  NX * NY * sizeof(double);  // define the memory size which needs to use in this application

    //declare V1 in host
    double* hos_V1 ;
    double* hos_V3 ;

    double* dev_V1 ;
    double* dev_V3 ;

//  hos_V1 = new double[N];     // allocate storage for VL array
//  hos_V3 = new double[N];

    hos_V1 = (double*)malloc(bytes);
    hos_V3 = (double*)malloc(bytes);

//  dev_V1 = new double[N];     // allocate storage for VL array
//  dev_V3 = new double[N];


    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_V1, bytes);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_V3, bytes);


    Initial <<< blocks , threads >>> (dev_V1, dev_V3, NX, NY);

    cudaMemcpy(hos_V1, dev_V1, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(hos_V3, dev_V3, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaThreadSynchronize();

    for (int x = 0; x <= NX * NY; x++)
    {

        printf("V1[%d] = %f  \n", x, &hos_V1[x]);
        printf("V3[%d] = %f  \n", x, &hos_V3[x]);

    }
    printf("-----------------------------\n");

    Add2D <<< blocks, threads >> > (dev_V1, dev_V3, NX, NY);

    cudaThreadSynchronize(); //Sync CPU and GPU to start the timer  
    cudaMemcpy(hos_V1, dev_V1, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(hos_V3, dev_V3, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (int x = 0; x <= NX*NY; x++)
    {
        
            printf("V1[%d] = %f  \n", x, &hos_V1[x]);
            printf("V3[%d] = %f  \n", x, &hos_V3[x]);
        
    }

    // free the memory allocated on the GPU
    cudaFree(dev_V1);
    cudaFree(dev_V3);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why are you printing &hos_V1[x] and not hos_V1[x]?!

Comment: I am going to repeat my advice from your last question -- " Comment out all the CUDA code and run your program and watch it blow up or print nonsense, and then ask yourself why". It is a waste of time trying to use CUDA if you don't understand the basics of the underlying C style language on which it relies. Both of your questions had elementary mistakes in the host code which have nothing to do with CUDA. [SO] is not a free basic mistake spotting service, please do not treat it like one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing &hos_V1[x] and &hos_V3[x], instead of hos_V1[x] and hos_V3[x]. I am sure you want to actually print the contents of the arrays.

```
for (int x = 0; x <= NX * NY; x++)
{

    printf("V1[%d] = %f  \n", x, hos_V1[x]);
    printf("V3[%d] = %f  \n", x, hos_V3[x]);

}
```

It might be useful for you to enable warnings while compiling. NVCC (or gcc, as that is host-code) suggested to me that you might be printing the wrong thing.
edit:as pointed out by others, there are still more "systemic" issues with the code you provided.

Comment: Thank you very much! I use & because at the first while it was printing some address so I was wondering if I should use &. Now, it is fine!! Thank you for answering and happy new year!!!!

Comment: There are other defects in the code, such as the fact that the `Add2D` kernel will index into the `V3` array out-of-bounds. The bounds-checking if-test for both kernels is also broken.  This issues are readily discoverable using `cuda-memcheck`.

Comment: You basically tried to print the address of a dereferenced pointer. instead of printing *(hosV1 + x), you tried to print &(*(hosV1 + x)), but in a floating point format, which is why you got 0 as an output.